# Set focus in LWC on anchor tag

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I need to set focus on the element inside an LWC component on button click. I have tried with adding data-id but I'm still unable to set focus on it.

```
<template if:true={showDiv}>
    <div title="My informative div" role="alert"  aria-live="assertive" >
        <a data-id="myFocussedLink" onclick={doSomething} href={customMessage} tabindex="0">{customMessage}</a>
    </div>
</template>
```

TabIndex is not setting the focus on the link.

In JavaScript, below line is returning me null so I can set focus and receive an error:

```
this.template.querySelector(`[data-id="${myFocussedLink}"]`)).focus();
```

Div is visible when some other action on the page is complete. I can see the div but the focus is not set on the link as soon as div renders on the page. Could someone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `showDiv`, the system needs time to redraw the elements, which don't happen in real time. You need a [short breather for the DOM to catch up](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/lCiKLRsM3nbBFYuC6EML/src/app.js):

```
  focusAnchor() {
    this.showDiv = true;
    setTimeout(()=>this.template.querySelector('[data-id="myFocussedLink"]').focus());
  }
```

P.S. `[data-id="${myFocussedLink}"]` is trying to insert the variable `myFocussedLink` into the string instead of the actual ID. I'm not sure if you meant to do this, or just got "lost" trying different things.